# Database Schema for Claims Authentication

Tags: sql, database-design

On a database I have the tables: USERS, USERS_PROFILES, USERS_CLAIMS.

```
create table dbo.USERS
(
  Id int identity not null, 
  Username nvarchar (120) not null,
  Email nvarchar (120) not null
);
create table dbo.USERS_PROFILES
(
  Id int not null,
  [Name] nvarchar (80) not null
);
create table dbo.USERS_CLAIMS
(
  Id int not null,
  [Type] nvarchar (200) not null,
  Value nvarchar (200) not null,
);
```

I am using Claims authorization. When a user signs up and Identity is created.
The identity contains claims and each claim has a type and a value:

UsernameType > Username from USERS
  EmailType > Email from USERS
  NameType > Name from USERS_PROFILES
  RoleType > Directly from USERS_CLAIMS

So I am creating the Identity from many columns in 3 tables.

I ended up with this because I migrated to Claims Authentication.

**QUESTION**

Should I move the Username, Email and Name to USERS_CLAIMS?
The USERS_PROFILES table would disappear ...
And USERS table would contain only info like "UserId, LastLoginDate, CreatedDate, ..."

If I want get a user by username I would just get the Claim of type username ...

If I want to sign in the user I just get all claims and create the identity.

So the Identity Model is much similar to the SQL tables.

Does this make sense? How would you design the tables?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a key value store.  They are a nightmare to query in SQL.  Consider the difficulty of querying user attributes by a value on the `USER_CLAIMS` table.  Example:

```
-- Users with name and email by username
SELECT p.ID, p.Username, p.Name, p.Email, u.LastLoggedIN
FROM USER_PROFILES p
INNER JOIN Users u on p.ID = u.ID
WHERE p.ID = @UserID

-- Users with name and email by username with a claims table
-- Does not specify whether there is only one email, so this could return multiple
-- rows for a single user.
SELECT p.ID, cUName.Value as Username, cName.Value as Name, cEMail.Value as Email, u.LastLoggedIN
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER_CLAIMS cName ON u.ID = cName.ID and cName.[Type] = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER_CLAIMS cUName ON u.ID = cUName.ID and cUName.[Type] = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier'
LEFT OUTER JOIN USER_CLAIMS cEmail ON u.ID = cEmail.ID and cEmail.[Type] = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/email'
WHERE p.ID = @UserID
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I fear ... Should I have maybe a Roles table for the roles and store the other information on USERS table? And then migrate all that info to a Claims Identity on my application?

Comment: Yes.  The fact that you are presenting the data via claims should not significantly alter your schema.  Make the data store easy to access and manipulate.  It is far easer to return multiple claims from a single row than it is to return a single row from multiple claims.

Answer (score 2):

Can a user have multiple profiles?  If not, there is no need for the "USERS_PROFILES" table.  Keep the "Username" and "Email" columns on the "USERS" table.  If you put them on the "USERS_CLAIMS" table, you would be storing redundant information anytime a user files a claim.

I am not sure what kind of tracking you'd like to have for your users, but I would recommend having a separate table that tracks when a user signs in.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS_LOG (user_id INT, log_in DATETIME);
```

You can then get rid of the "LastLoginDate" on your "USERS" table and do a join to get the last time the user signed in.  It'll give you more ways to track your users and you won't be creating blocks on your "USERS" table by updating it constantly.

Comment: Instead of a USERS_Log table why not using the Logging table that I already have? With a Flag on each record I would be able to pick the the items for that user ... Maybe more flexible and using a table that already exists?

Comment: What about the user name, birhtday, and so on ... Would you place it in USERS table to? USERS and USER_Profiles are splited tables ... On USERS I placed all info necessary for the authentication to work. On Profiles I place other info like name, birthday, ... This changes from application to application ... But the USERS table is the same ... This way is easier to mantain and change things from one application to another

Comment: About the USER_CLAIMS. Would this be only for Roles? Or for everything that does not be do be queried? In fact I never know ... Maybe I need to query users by roles ... I really not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: @MDMoura Place the birthdate, username, etc... on the "USERS" table.  It sounds like you really don't need an "USERS_PROFILES" table since all users only have 1 profile.  You don't have to worry about only using the "USERS" table for authentication since READS on tables do not block each other.  If you have a logging table already, use that.